# Exporting a django template table to xlsx

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to use django template for the first time and I need to export some data. How can I export a table in my django template to a .xlsx file? Is there any method? here is my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests


from .utils import most_frequent, get_json_values, get_max_dict

def launches(request):
"""main request. Retrieve the year that had most launches"""
response_launches = requests.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches? 
filter=launch_year')
launches = response_launches.json()
launch_years = get_json_values('launch_year',launches)
result_launches = most_frequent(launch_years)

"""retrieve the launch site most used for launches """
response_sites = requests.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches? 
filter=launch_site')
sites = response_sites.json()
launch_sites = get_json_values("launch_site", sites)
result_sites = get_max_dict(launch_sites,'site_id')

"""retrieve the number of launches between 2019 and 2021"""
response_2019_2021 = requests.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches? 
start=2019&end=2021')
launches_2019_2021 = response_2019_2021.json()
result_2019_2021 = len(launches_2019_2021)

data = {
    "year_most_launches": str(result_launches),
    "launch_sites":result_sites,
    "launches_2019_2021":str(result_2019_2021)
    }

return render(request,"main/launches.html", {"data":data})
```

And that's my table inside my template:

```
       <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year with most launches</th>
                    <th>Launch site with most launches</th>
                    <th>Number of launches between 2019 and 2021</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                {% for element in data.values %}
                    <td>{{ element }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I couldn't find a way to do it so any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I create a function in the view that handle all the data and insert it into a Excel file.
Let me give you the code, it may help you.

```
    def export_excel(self, elements):
    output = io.BytesIO() 
    workbook = Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # r = Row and c = Column
    r = 0
    c = 0

    # Table header
    table_headers = [
        # Define your headers name here
        ''
    ]

    for header in table_headers:
        worksheet.write(r, c, header)
        c += 1

    r += 1

    for element in elements:
        # write your data in the excel following the same command

        worksheet.write(r, 0, element.data_name)
        r += 1

    workbook.close()
    output.seek(0)
    content_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type=content_type)
    file_name = _('file_name')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=" + file_name + ".xlsx"
    return response
```

Let me know if it was useful

Comment: Could you tell me the modules that you're using for this function? Also thanks for sharing the code!

Comment: just add import io and from xlsxwriter import Workbook. You need to install xlsxwriter from https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/ first.